# Cambiar zona horaria en BD phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hola tengo problemas con el horario el servidor del proveedor de hosting esta en UTC así que ya intente cambiar el  archivo .htaccess pero no me cambia la zona horaria de la tabla ya intente con estas opciones en sql pero tampoco funcionan

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Mexico_City'; NO RECONOCE LA ZONA

SET time_zone = '+01:00'; FUNCIONA, PERO NO CAMBIA NADA

SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Mexico_City'; ACCESO DENEGADO
```

espero contar con su ayuda muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Que proveedor de hosting tienes? en algunos casos se puede cambiar la zona horaria desde el panel del proveedor

Comment: Hola tengo Hostinger de hecho ya me comunique con soporte y tampoco pueden ayudarme :(

Comment: phpmyadmin no es una base de datos.

Comment: bueno me refiero al sistema phpmyadmin cambiar la zona horaria que tiene por defecto

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías decir por favor con qué fines quieres hacer esto? Realmente no entiendo por qué motivo habría que cambiar la zona horaria en la base de datos.

Comment: Hola gracias por la bienvenida. si claro lo que pasa es que estoy subiendo un sistema POS punto de venta y lo que pasa es que como tiene en la base de datos la hora central y soy de mexico entonces se desfasa por 6 horas la hora actual y al momento de guardar una venta me la guarda con ese desfase, ejemplo si hoy siendo 13/03/2019 creo una venta a las 6:15 pm lo guarda como si la venta se hubiera realizado el dia 14/03/2019 a las 00:15 hrs y eso dato ya es para las ventas del dia siguiente por eso es muy importante cambiar la zona horaria de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que irte a phpmyadmin, seleccionar la base de datos e ingresarle la siguiente consulta SQL...

```
SET tome_zone = '-03:00';
```

En el ejemplo ingreso la zona horaria de Buenos Aires.

Comment: Ojo, es time_zone ;) Por cierto, leé [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.